# initifywait --exclude does not fire when there is at least one not excluded file

Tags: ubuntu, inotify

I am using this command to watch a directory:

```
inotifywait -r -e modify,create,delete --exclude ".*(\.(git|idea)|(.*(___jb_tmp___|___jb_old___)))" my-dir
```

However, it does not work like I intend. What I want is that it does only NOT fire if every file that was changed is excluded. If there is at least one file that is NOT excluded and changes, then I want inotifywait to "fire".

My overall plan is to push code to a remove server whenever a python file or something else that is relevant is changed. I do not want to push code when only meta files from my IDE (PyCharm) or git files are changed.

Is there a way to do this?

Right now inotifywait does not fire when I change a python file in PyCharm since there are some files changed that end with **_jb_tmp_**. However, if I change a python file by hand, it works (e.g. in nano or vim).

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with simpler  ```--exclude``` values?

Comment: It is very hard to find simpler values that take care of all the files that PyCharm writes... Do you have a simpler idea?

Comment: It is really strange. When I use `--exclude "(___jb_tmp___|___jb_old___)$"` it fires when I save a file in PyCharm (but the event is called '.git/ CREATE index.lock'). When I use `--exclude "(index\.lock|___jb_tmp___|___jb_old___)$"` and save a file, nothing happens. It looks like PyCharm is not really writing python files? But this makes no sense

Comment: I tried the following command: `inotifywait -r -m -e modify,create,delete  my-dir` (note the -m flag to monitor and see all events) and found that there is no event for the .py files when I save them in pycharm. The only events:
my-dir/patch_experts/ CREATE densenet.py___jb_tmp___
my-dir/patch_experts/ MODIFY densenet.py___jb_tmp___
my-dir/patch_experts/ DELETE densenet.py___jb_old___
my-dir/.idea/ CREATE workspace.xml___jb_tmp___
my-dir/.idea/ MODIFY workspace.xml___jb_tmp___
my-dir/.idea/ DELETE workspace.xml___jb_old___
my-dir/.git/ CREATE index.lock
my-dir/.git/ DELETE index.lock

Comment: When I use sublime instead of PyCharm it works (I see 'MODIFY main.py'). So the reason for the problem is PyCharm, but I have no idea why this happens

Comment: I know nothing about PyCharm.  If you don't know what files it is creating, maybe you should leave it out of the equation for now.  I was thinking that you could create a temporary/scratch directory and try `--exclude "foo"`.  If that works correctly, try ``--exclude "foo|bar"``, and add complexity until you reproduce the error.  … … … … … … …  … … … … …  … … … … … … …  OTOH, if you have determined to your satisfaction that the reason for the problem is PyCharm, then I wish you good luck; I won't be able to help you.

Comment: I found the problem in PyCharm: When "safe write" is enabled, it first saves changes to temporary files (this is the `___jb_temp___` stuff). If I disable "safe write", it works as intended. But I don't know what side effects this might have

Comment: See my own answer for how it works

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments to my question, I found that the problem was not caused by `inotifywait` but by PyCharm. It turned out that PyCharm has an option called "safe write" that tells the IDE to write changes to temporary files first and if this succeeds, it deletes the original file and renames the tempory file to the original file name.

This is why `inotifywait` only sees events like these:

```
$ inotifywait -r -m -e modify,create,delete my-dir

my-dir/ CREATE main.py___jb_tmp___ 
my-dir/ MODIFY main.py___jb_tmp___ 
my-dir/ DELETE main.py___jb_old___ 
my-dir/.idea/ CREATE workspace.xml___jb_tmp___ 
my-dir/.idea/ MODIFY workspace.xml___jb_tmp___ 
my-dir/.idea/ DELETE workspace.xml___jb_old___ 
my-dir/.git/ CREATE index.lock 
my-dir/.git/ DELETE index.lock
```

So I disabled safe write in PyCharm and now use this command:

```
inotifywait -r -e modify,create,delete --exclude ".*(\.git|\.idea)" my-dir
```

This is doing exactly what I want. The events I see from `inotifywait` are like this:

> my-dir/ MODIFY main.py